# Can i use font-awesome in android's edittext?

Tags: android, plugins, font-awesome

I have added font-awesome .tff file to the assets folder, initlaized some of the icons in the strings.xml file, changed the typefaces of the entities i will use font-awesome in and tried using font-awesome on buttons and it worked, but i did the same for edittexts but there are strings of numbers instead of the icon. Any idea what i can do?

Comment: I think one possible solution to create a custom keyboard for your  EditText

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ans:  you just set the string directly in xml  like:
      `android:text="&#xf042";`
and use the typeface set in edittext  ,like

```
Typeface font_awesome =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
app_menutxt.setTypeface(font_awesome);
```

in programme : `app_menutxt.setText("\uf042");`

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate the quick reply.